# Inject Hashtable in Spring.Net

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, spring.net

Can you help me configure Spring.Net to inject a pre-defined hashtable in an object property?

I've done something like this:

```
<object name="myHashtable" type="Hashtable">
  <map>
    <entry key="key1" value="value1" />
    <entry key="key2" value="value2" />
  </map>
</object>
```

but it seems that MAP node does not exists!

SOLVED

The exact configuration is:

```
<object id="myHashtable" type="System.Collections.Hashtable">
    <constructor-arg>
        <dictionary key-type="decimal?" value-type="int" merge="0">
            <entry key="1" value="31" />
            <entry key="2" value="32" />
            <entry key="3" value="33" />
            <entry key="4" value="34" />
        </dictionary>
    </constructor-arg>
</object>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a hashtable with an `IDictionary` as constructor, e.g.:

```xml
<object id="MyObject" type="MyClass">

  <property name="MyHashTable">
    <object type="System.Collections.Hashtable, mscorlib">
      <constructor-arg name="d">
        <dictionary>
          <entry key="key1" value="value1" />
          <entry key="key2" value="value2" />
        </dictionary>
      </constructor-arg>
    </object>
  </property>

</object>
```